# Renumber Table or Post through Page links to two files

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two files. A main file and a details file. The details file is embedded in the main file allowing the user to scroll the records in the detail file.

I need to be able to post the same variables to both files, and would like to do this via the page links set up by my pagination code.

A typical line in the pagination code reads

```
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $padd1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$padd1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' .  $padd1 .   '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$padd1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$T able_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> .<a href="' . details_file.php . '?pn=' . $padd1 .  '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$padd1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$T able_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
```

Clicking the page link would post to the embedded url and the main file url simultaneously. I actually probably only need to post two variables $jrny and $sess to the main file, and all the variables to the details_file.

Can this be done?

Apologies for the previous way I phrased the question.

Comment: I see a lot of text, but no code

Comment: How/why do the users choose the 2 tables?

Comment: One table is about geographical information- a variety of different journeys. The other tables are about data that they might link to the geographical information at their own discretion.

Comment: ``$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?  pn=' . $padd1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$padd1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';``

This code allows users to go to the next page on one file but I need to post variables to another parent file simultaneously. How might the code above be added to to allow that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea on how you can use a join for any 2 unrelated tables...

We can give one id to each table "on the fly" within a query... and use these ids to join the tables so... You end up with a single table to display, paginate using limit, etc...

For example... with these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `field1`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `field2`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'), 
                            ('f', 'f'), ('g', 'g'), ('h', 'h'), ('i', 'i'), ('j', 'j'), 
                            ('k', 'k'), ('l', 'l'), ('m', 'm'), ('n', 'n'), ('o', 'o'), 
                            ('p', 'p'), ('q', 'q'), ('r', 'r');
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `field3`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `field4`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'), 
                            ('f', 'f'), ('g', 'g'), ('h', 'h'), ('i', 'i'), ('j', 'j'), 
                            ('k', 'k'), ('l', 'l'), ('m', 'm'), ('n', 'n'), ('o', 'o'), 
                            ('p', 'p'), ('q', 'q'), ('r', 'r'), ('s', 's'), ('t', 't'), 
                            ('u', 'u'), ('v', 'v'), ('w', 'w'), ('x', 'x'), ('yy', 'y');
COMMIT;
```

We could have a join like this:

```
SET @a=0;
SET @b=0;
SELECT tt1.field1, tt1.field2, 
    tt2.field3, tt2.field4 FROM 
    (
        (SELECT t1.* FROM 
            (SELECT @a:=@a+1 as id, field1, field2 FROM table1) AS t1) 
         AS tt1 

         INNER JOIN 

        (SELECT t2.* FROM 
            (SELECT @b:=@b+1 as id, field3, field4 FROM table2) AS t2) 
         AS tt2 

         ON tt1.id=tt2.id

    );
```

So you have the results in one single recordset to play with.

The only care you have to have... to know which table has more rows to decide whether you need a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Thanks @Julio Soares, you put a lot of time into that answer. The query at the bottom looks like a subquery I did in Microsoft Access to accomplish a similar outcome.

For the moment I am going to try to get a POST to send to two separate files- and I'll cycle back to your solution if I'm still stuck. 

Sincere thanks.